# Function-calling Context

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jscript

I thought the JavaScript, below, would cause`obj.fn`to run in the context of`entryPoint().`

But when`obj.fn()`runs, a`'locVar is undefined'`exception is raised.

```
  function entryPoint () {
    var locVar = "xxx";
    var obj    = {};

    PassRcvr(obj);

    obj.fn();

  }

  function PassRcvr(passedObj) { // Being an object, the arg is passed by reference.
    passedObj.fn = function  () {
      alert(locVar);
    }
  }
```

The JScript, below, however *does* run with an awareness of`locVar.`

```
  function entryPoint () {
    var locVar = "xxx";
    var obj = {};

    PassRcvr(obj);

    obj.fn();

    function PassRcvr(passedObj) {
        passedObj.fn = function  () {
        alert(locVar);
      }
    }

  }
```

Why isn’t`obj.fn()`aware of the context in which it is called, in both cases, rather than just the one?

Comment: Javascript is lexically (or "statically") scoped language, what you're looking for is "dynamic" scoping. There are languages that support it, but Javascript doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *context* is the value of `this`. You aren't using it, so it isn't relevant to your problem.

The *scope* is not passed. A function keeps the scope it was declared in (that is why we can use closures in JS). Since `PassRcvr` isn't defined inside `entryPoint` in the first example, it doesn't have access to variables that are scoped to `entryPoint`.

Comment: I was unaware that the JS language has the specification that functions keep the scope in which they are declared.  That certainly would explain it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `PassRcvr` is located in global scope, while the `locVar` is within `entryPoint` function's local scope - that is why it cannot be accessed.

In the second case both `PassRcvr` and `locVar` are in one local scope.